# Error while JSON Object request

Tags: android

I am having error while returning JSON request, my program is not compiling nd getting this error .. !

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class
```

Comment: show `build.gradle`

Comment: Here is my [Build.gradlel](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6c682419327e9a32d05eb0b38bd680b3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

complie this

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

add this in your inside your app dir `build.gradle file`

```
android{
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley'
    all*.exclude module: 'toolbox'
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class

If you using

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

You should add this in your <kbd>**build.gradle**</kbd> section .

```
  configurations{
    all*.exclude module: 'toolbox'
}
```

**FYI**

**`mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19`** is <s>**`Deprecated`**</s> . Don't use .

You should use **[Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)**

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```